# Using django-dynamic-formset with CreateWithInlinesView from django-extra-views - multiple formsets

Tags: jquery, python, django, django-class-based-views, inline-formset

I got 3 models:

```
class Client(models.Model):
     first_name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
     last_name = models.CharField(max_length=40)

class Phone(models.Model):
    number = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    client = models.ForeignKey(Client)

class ClientEmail(models.Model):
    client = models.ForeignKey(Client)
    address = models.EmailField(verbose_name='Email')
```

one form and two inline formsets:

```
class ClientForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Client


class PhoneFormSet(InlineFormSet):
    model = Phone
    extra = 1


class EmailFormSet(InlineFormSet):
    model = ClientEmail
    extra = 1
```

view:

```
class ClientCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateWithInlinesView):
    model = Client
    inlines = [PhoneFormSet, EmailFormSet,]
```

and working template:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block extra_head_script %}
<script src="{{ STATIC_URL }}js/jquery.formset.js"></script>
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
<form action="." method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <table>
        {{ form.as_table }}
    </table>
    {% for formset in inlines %}
        <div id="{{ formset.prefix }}">
        {% for subform in formset.forms %}
            <table>
            {{ subform.as_table }}
            </table>
        {% endfor %}
        {{ formset.management_form }}
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
    <input type="submit" value="Add client" class="submit"/>
</form>
{% endblock %}
```

I just started using ClassBasedViews and cant figure out how to use [django-dynamic-formset](https://github.com/elo80ka/django-dynamic-formset/) js with [django-extra-views](https://github.com/AndrewIngram/django-extra-views) in my template.

Answer (score 4):

Oh my head ...  I figured it out:

```
{% block extra_footer_script %}
<script type="text/javascript">
       $(function() {
           {% for formset in inlines %}
           $('div#FormSet{{ formset.prefix }}').formset({
               prefix: '{{ formset.prefix }}',
               formCssClass: 'dynamic-formset{{ forloop.counter }}'
           });
           {% endfor %}
       })
   </script>
{% endblock %}
```

If you see any errors please point them to me. Also appreciate any better ideas.

For those who want to use this - Yes it should work with any number of formsets

Comment: line 5 should be `$('div#{{ formset.prefix }}').formset({` since you don't have `FormSet` in the div's id of the original question (or you could add `FormSet` to line 13 in template)

Comment: can you please tell me how did you add new subform at client side?? I want to add new subform as needed on the client side.